# I want to animate div after a timeout

Tags: jquery

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e5ana/9/

There are 5 scenes and the default scene loads with the page. Mouse over the pins in the map and the scenes change. In the actual site the black area hides the extra scenes.

Here's the code for one of the scenes:

```
    $("a.dt").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".town").filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
    bottom: '0px'
  }, 500);
    $("#dt").animate({
    bottom: '126px'
  }, 500);
});
```

Where I'm stuck is...

If no pins are hovered after ten seconds, I want whatever scene is visible to animate down, and I want the default scene (id="dt") to animate up.

I came close when I added the timeout code to each mouseenter function, but the default scene seemed to get stuck animated up.  In other words, the mouseenter on asnother pin failed to lower the default scene even though it has a class of "town."

Here's the timeout code I'm trying:

```
var t;
var del = 10000; //Ms delay 
    $(document).mousemove(function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    var t = setTimeout(function(){
        //If the mouse is not moved
        $(".town").animate({
            bottom: '0px'
        }, 500);
        $("#dt").animate({
            bottom: '126px'
        }, 500);
    }, del);
});
```

What am I missing?

=====================

So as I commented below, eliminating the duplicate global 'var t' got this working. Thanks!

Now I'm trying to only run the code if the default scene is hidden. That's because if the default scene is visible, the code runs and it animates that scene down and back up again.

Here's what I'm trying...

```
if ($('#dt').css('bottom') == '0px') {
var t;
var del = 10000; //Ms delay 
    $(document).mousemove(function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function(){
        //If the mouse is not moved
        $(".town").animate({
            bottom: '0px'
        }, 500);
        $("#dt").animate({
            bottom: '126px'
        }, 500);
    }, del);
});
}
```

But it does not work. No script errors are thrown and nothing happens to the scenes.

Updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/webguy262/e5ana/18/

Comment: You are declaring `t` twice, once as a global variable, then as a local. Just declare it globally.

Comment: yea, just replace the `var t = ` with `t = `

Comment: And you should refactor your redundant code

Comment: Thanks, gentlemen, declaring t twice was the issue.  Works perfectly now!